# How to Connect to WCF service with Ionic project and angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, wcf, ionic-framework

Hi I have an issue trying to figure out how to connect from my ionic project to WCF service on another pc (C# Application) on the local network. I have ensured that the connection between the pc's are working and that the web service is working. I am using `Ionic serve` to run my project in the browser, and I have follow the steps by changing my proxy for CORS but still the same error is showing :
`GET http://localhost:53101/TruckService.svc net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

http://localhost:53101/TruckService.svc (My WCF Address)

and also this runs through all of my html files in the templates folder before the error shows:  `XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8100/templates/tab-account.html".`

this is my controller for connecting to the service I found on a tutorial.

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://localhost:53101/TruckService.svc').
  success(function(data,GetQuoteAsync){
    console.log(GetQuoteAsync),
    console.log(data);
  });
})
```

I am fairly new with Angularjs and Ionic and I am not sure exactly where I am going wrong. if I left out something or wasn't clear enough please let me know.

thanks

Comment: how can it be localhost if it's on a different machine ?

Comment: the web service is running on another pc as localhost.. also my app is on  the default server when running ionic serve. @eranotzap

Comment: it's localhost on the other pc , when trying to contact it from any where else you need to specify the ip address .

Comment: Both of the pc's are on the same wifi and has got the same ip address would that make a difference? @eranotzap

Comment: is there any authentication needed to assess your service ?

Comment: No I have doubled checked it is open to access.. @eranotzap

Comment: maybe post your service configurations .. it might help to resolve the issue

Comment: I dont think the problem lies with the wcf itself but from my mobile app.. When I connect with a c# application it connects fine @eranotzap

Comment: ok but you should give as much info as you can on the scenario. 
because it seems ok it's probably something small that wither you didn't notice or is a kind of cavetie of wcf or ionic. you should give people a chance to see.

Comment: well any way it's probably the ip address. why would you think that 2 pc on the same router would have the same ip...

Comment: I have pinged all devices on network and also check in google for ip address and is set the same.. Sorry I have tried to show as much info as I can..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the localhost in my `$http.get`link I set it to the ip address from the other pc like this `http://192.168.1.18/TruckService.svc`